# Get user OpenID URL without user interaction

Tags: google-chrome-app

I have an packaged app in the Chrome Web Store that I'd like to transition from a paid app to a free one with in app purchases. I need to be able to detect if the current user had paid for the app previously.

To be able to use the licensing API, I need the current user's OpenID URL. I was able to get this to work using chrome.identity and a popup dialog that the user has to authorize. But it is a bad experience and kind of a scary dialog.

For hosted apps, it's possible to get the user's OpenID URL without any user interaction or authorization. (see [How to skip the OpenID approval screen](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/identify_user)). It would be fantastic if somebody knows how to make this work without user interaction for packaged apps.

I've detailed some of the approaches I've tried on this chromium-apps [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/t5N_MqD4O4Q). I suspect it may be possible to do this with chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow but I wasn't able to discover the exact incantation of parameters to google's oauth/openid endpoints to make this happen silently.

Comment: Are you writing a hosted app with Google App Engine? if yes there is a work around.. else that is quite difficult, may be a third party app can help!

Comment: Also specify you are using new account or Old one  Prior to November 19, 2013. As google has launched new  Google Apps Marketplace experience! that requires many changes..

Comment: This is a packaged app, not a hosted app. In regards to your other question, I would want to be able to do this for any user, regardless of when they created their account. My google account naturally is many years prior to that date created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to refer to this [Link1 Parameters](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#Parameters)

this parameters are different techniques using that you can do this task..

also To bypass the Login/approval screen refer this [link2](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/identify_user)
Here in the section `How to skip the OpenID approval screen` the details are explained which you can use..

And In case of packaged app this should ask for permanent permission that will help in OAuth throughout the life of app..

Client Library [JavaScript Based](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js)

Authentication using [Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication)

After your comment I thought this you can bind in your app.!!

Let me know what works for you..

Comment: Thanks for the information. The first link (OpenID 2.0 Parameters) I have now looked at more carefully and I will try to use launchWebAuthFlow with all the parameters setup, and with check_immediate and see if that works. The "link2" I am very familiar with, though it applies to "Hosted apps", not "packaged apps".

Comment: if the above does not work, I have added more links in my answer that will give you JavaScript based library,(Newly Introduced by google) that might reduce your work see the subsequent link how to use library for authentication..